# Min Cost to reach destination using only diagonal moves

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, graph, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Given a infinite grid , we need to find out the minimum cost required to reach a destination from given source. Cost is calculated as below.
Only diagonal movements are allowed.
The cost is incremented only when direction is changed .Similar to Bishop move in chess. you can move as many cells in the same diagonal as you want that will not have any additional cost. if source is (1,1) and destination is (3,3) the cost is 1.

Can someone help me with efficient algorithm to achieve this.

Comment: " if source is (1,1) and destination is (3,3) the cost is 1."  Why?  No change in direction is required.

Comment: You can get from anywhere to anywhere with no more than 1 change in direction.

Comment: If source and destination are on same diagonal, cost is zero.  Otherwise cost is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get from anywhere to anywhere with no more than 1 change in direction.  so if source and destination are on same diagonal, cost is zero. Otherwise cost is 1.

To find the actual path:

```
Let source be at xs, ys
Let destination be xd, yd

Specify four diagonal lines passing through the points

y = ys + ( xs - x )
y = ys - ( xs - x )

Is destination on one of these lines?  If so, done.

y = yd + ( xd - x )
y = yd - ( xd - x )

Calculate line intersection ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection )
There will be two - select one
Travel from source to intersection point
Travel from intersection to destination
```

Comment: To understand why this is so, note that the two diagonals form a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) for the 2D plane of integers (just like the X-and Y-axis). In other words, any vector (including the source-destination displacement vector) in this plane can be written as a linear combination of the two diagonals. Thus any displacement can be achieved by moving `x` units along the first diagonal and then `y` units along the second diagonal. If `x` and/or `y` is zero, then you don't need to move along the corresponding diagonal at all.